# Cannot run script from command line despite script being set to executable -- I get "command not found"

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I am running the script from inside the directory that contains it and doing so via sudo.

```
$ sudo launch_16GB.sh
sudo: launch_16GB.sh: command not found
$ ls
actions    contrib         functions       launch_8GB.sh  README.md
clean.sh   drivers         iso             launch.sh
config.sh  dumpkeys.cache  launch_16GB.sh  MAINTAINERS
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have run the command `sudo` assumes you want it to look in the directories defined by the `PATH` variable. If the command was `sudo ./launch_16GB.sh`, `sudo` would know to look in the current directory.

Comment: In the default configuration, `sudo` searches its own `secure_path`, as defined in `/etc/sudoers`, rather than either the invoking user's or root's `PATH`